# Php script as daemon

Tags: linux, bash, shell, daemon

I am new to php daemons. I am using the below script to fire Daemon.php script. But i am getting error while executing this below bash script via shell

The error is,

```
exit: 0RETVAL=0: numeric argument required
```

Please help me resolve this error

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#   /etc/init.d/Daemon
#
# Starts the at daemon
#
# chkconfig: 345 95 5
# description: Runs the demonstration daemon.
# processname: Daemon

# Source function library.
#. /etc/init.d/functions

#startup values
log=/var/log/Daemon.log

#verify that the executable exists
test -x /home/godlikemouse/Daemon.php || exit 0RETVAL=0

#
#   Set prog, proc and bin variables.
#
prog="Daemon"
proc=/var/lock/subsys/Daemon
bin=/home/godlikemouse/Daemon.php
start() {
    # Check if Daemon is already running
    if [ ! -f $proc ]; then
        echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
        daemon $bin --log=$log
        RETVAL=$?
        [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch $proc
        echo
    fi

    return $RETVAL
}

stop() {
    echo -n $"Stopping $prog: "
    killproc $bin
    RETVAL=$?
    [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && rm -f $proc
    echo
        return $RETVAL
}

restart() {
    stop
    start
}   

reload() {
    restart
}   

status_at() {
    status $bin
}

case "$1" in
start)
    start
    ;;
stop)
    stop
    ;;
reload|restart)
    restart
    ;;
condrestart)
        if [ -f $proc ]; then
            restart
        fi
        ;;
status)
    status_at
    ;;
*)

echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|condrestart|status}"
    exit 1
esac

exit $?
exit $RETVAL
```

Comment: There is several syntax errors in this script presented. To highlight several:

* echo $"Usage (should be just echo "Usage ..." since the string in ".." is not a variable
* Double exit statements, the second one for $RETVAL is never ran.
* exit 0RETVAL is not the same as exit $RETVAL, and one should just be using exit 1 instead to denote an error, exit 0 means the script ran correctly
* $prog is defined but never used

Comment: @Dwight, whether the string "is a variable" is irrelevant. Red Hat ships init scripts with `$""` strings for internationalization purposes. To be sure, if the OP is not building gettext tables for their own init scripts, there's little point to copying that practice here -- but it _is_ something the OP presumably copied from a vendor script, and is not inherently an error in a script starting with `#!/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line produces the error:

```
test -x /home/godlikemouse/Daemon.php || exit 0RETVAL=0
```

If you want to set the the value of `RETVAL` to 0 you first need to remove the 0 as you can not have variables that start with a number.

Then you remove the value set from the second statement so it will exit in case Daemon.php does not exist.

```
test -x /home/godlikemouse/Daemon.php || exit
```

You can also remove the 2 empty echo statements inside the start and stop functions as the do nothing.

There are also errors in the case statement. You need to quote the case options and can remove the last exit block as the `exit $?` will trigger the exit before.

```
case "$1" in
"start")
    start
    ;;
"stop")
    stop
    ;;
"reload"|"restart")
    restart
    ;;
"condrestart")
        if [ -f $proc ]; then
            restart
        fi
        ;;
"status")
    status_at
    ;;
```

Comment: `RETVAL=0 && exit` makes no sense -- the value of `RETVAL` is thrown away by the `exit`.

Answer (score 0):

There is several syntax and logic errors in this script presented. To highlight several:

- `echo $"Usage` (should be just `echo "Usage ..."` since the string in ".." is not a variable
- Double exit statements, the second one for `$RETVAL` is never ran.
- `exit 0RETVAL` is not the same as `exit $RETVAL`, and one should just be using `exit 1` instead to denote an error, `exit 0` means the script ran correctly

  - `$prog` is defined but never used
  - `test -x` is to check for executable bit enabled in the given path. `test -f` is safer when testing for a file, `test -d` safer for testing directories, and `test -L` is safer when testing symlinks. Combine the `test -f` and `test -x` to ensure there is no race conditions or worst. (example: `(test -f /home/godlikemouse/Daemon.php && test -x /home/godlikemouse/Daemon.php) || exit 1)`)

Further details on creating sysv init scripts can be read at http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.0.0/LSB-generic/LSB-generic/iniscrptact.html and bash scripting can be read at http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/index.html. It is strongly encouraged to learn both before writing system control programs such as init scripts.

Comment: `$"foo"` is internationalization support; it has nothing to do with variables, but uses `gettext()` to look for a version of the string `"foo"` translated to the local language.

Comment: Also, boo, hiss re: linking to the ABS (which has an unfortunate tendency to showcase antipatterns in its example code without distinguishing them from good practices). http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide makes a much stronger effort to be maintained in a way that leads towards good practices, and the bash-hackers wiki (http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/doku.php) is likewise better maintained.

Comment: Oh so anti-pattterns like say bashisms? like the $"foo" sort? Sorry to say but that does not work on every system since bash is _not_ default on every system only most linux desktop/servers and even then that is not reliable since again not every system is going to run bash 4.0.

Examples:

bash-4.3# tcsh
[root@tspadevtapp01al ~]# echo $"fubar"
Illegal variable name.

-bash-4.3# zsh #busybox behaves the same
[root@tspadevtapp01al]~# echo $"fubar"
$fubar

-bash-4.3# echo $"fubar"
fubar

LSB, freedesktop.org, and the Open Group all agree bashism are bad. mmkay

Comment: Of *course* `$"foo"` is a bashism -- but for a "bash scripting" guide to consider all bashisms bad would defeat its purpose; it might as well just be a "POSIX scripting" guide at that point. To be sure, there are bashisms that increase expressiveness enough to substantially increase the set of tools for which shell scripts are appropriate -- consider arrays. To _not_ teach those would be to do the community a disservice.

Comment: Getting back on subject -- I was pointing out that a very specific claim you made was incorrect (in the context of a script starting with `#!/bin/bash` in a question tagged `bash`), and you've yet to correct it.

Comment: @charles-duffy never once did I point out that starting with #!/bin/bash was incorrect and infact that is very much a correct way of starting a script in posix environments.

Comment: My point is that starting a script with `#!/bin/bash` makes bashisms such as `$""` no longer syntax errors, yet this answer still claims that they are. I did not at any time claim that you called starting a script with `#!/bin/bash` incorrect.

Comment: True using a shebang line that calls bash itself may enable bashism, but again not something that can be fully trusted since bash 4, yes most common, is not always map to /bin/bash. /bin/bash may be a symlink to busybox or ash.

Its always better for all to teach a new user the standards first then enlighten them to fanciful helpers than the other way around.

Comment: Pardon? Two responses: First, `$""` long predates bash 4 (if that's what you were meaning to say; otherwise, the intent behind the sentence referring to bash 4 eludes me). Second, any operating system where `/bin/bash` is a symlink to a shell which _is not bash_ is lying to its users in the same way that a system where `/bin/ls` were a symlink to `awk` would be lying -- and for a question about a script intended to run on such a bizarre system to be tagged `bash` rather than exclusively `sh` or `shell` would be an error on the part of the user posting it.

Comment: To be clear, you're more than welcome to say that you advise against use of `$""` for portability reasons; I would tend to agree. It's simply failing to correct the claim that `$""` _is an error_ in what is explicitly a bash script (by both the OP's shebang and their tagging of the question) to which I raise continued objection.